# Select columns from another table given an array with the column names

Tags: sql, arrays, clickhouse

Let's suppose I have this table `meta_table`

```
+------------+------------------------+
| table_name |       col_names        |
+------------+------------------------+
| t1         | {ID, PRICE, OPERATION} |
| t2         | {TYPE, PRICE, ANGLE}   |
+------------+------------------------+
```

where col_names has an array structure.

`t1` and `t2` have the columns contained in the array + some other columns which don't appear in the array.

First question: How can I select from tables `t1` and `t2` only the columns contained in the array from the column `col_names`?

Second question: the main purpose is to count the number of missings for each column within the array for each table and return it in a new column with an array structure:

```
+------------+------------------------+-----------+
| table_name |       col_names        |  n_miss   |
+------------+------------------------+-----------+
| t1         | {ID, PRICE, OPERATION} | {0, 1, 0} |
| t2         | {TYPE, PRICE, ANGLE}   | {0, 0, 1} |
+------------+------------------------+-----------+
```

Any ideas on how to do it?

I'm using Clickhouse

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: It is not possible to do using SQL - you cannot form the dynamic queries. Use the server-side to solve this task.

Comment: Thanks vladimir, as you said, I didn't find a way to do it so I ended up exporting the table and doing it in R

Answer (score 0):

This answers the original version of the question.

If I understand correctly, you can use `array join`.  I am not very familiar with Clickhouse syntax, but I think this is what you want:

```
select a.*
from t1 array join
     t1.array as a;
```

Comment: How that code is supposed to extract the columns from t2?